# Asymptotic of sine integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, asymptotics

How I can prove that $\int_1^N \frac{\sin ^ 2 x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ asymptotically equals to $\frac{\ln N}{N}$?

I tried to use partial integration, but it didn't give me good results. I calculated that integral in terms of $Si(x)$, but it also doesn't solve my problem. Can someone tell me, where I should look for?

Comment: From what I can tell and understand, these are not asymptotically equivalent. The integral converges as $N\to\infty$ to some positive number while the log ratio converges to 0.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $\int_N^\infty$? That's closer at least....